# Unable to install dependencies for albert on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dependencies, launcher, ubuntu-19.04

I am unable to install albert https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/ for my ubuntu 19.04

I have tried installing from https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert the deb package for 18.10 but there is a github comment which states that someone managed to use the 18.10 albert deb installed on a 19.04 https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/issues/799

I get this error when i try to install the dependencies by typing out sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The following packages will be REMOVED: albert 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 4,132 kB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 169759 files and directories currently installed.) Removing albert (0.16.1) ... Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ... Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ... libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity... /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK libdvd-pkg: apt-get checkfailed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```

Comment: I found the problem. I cannot install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+source/python3.6 this on my machine. Its a dependency. How do I install it?